# Bootstrap navbar menu is not working after ajax form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form where I am using Ajax form post as follows. That is working fine. But after the form post my navbar is not working. I am not able to click on the navbar.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ManageRates", "Rate", new AjaxOptions
{
    OnBegin = "RequestStart",
    OnSuccess = "RequestComplete",
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "RateListUpdated"
}))
```

What could be the issue? I couldn't find a proper answer for this solution. Please help me

Comment: Try a different approach to ajax, maybe try performing it with Javascript rather than razor?

Comment: that also  I tried. But same effect.